# Populating a target table from another table using same target table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have table A which and there are several other rated tables. 
I want to do conversion in phase manner. 
To do the conversion I am first creating a temprary table TMP, from table A (not all the records. Lets say X

```
CREATE TABLE TMP (EMP_ID NUMBER(9));

SELECT A.EMP_ID FROM A, TMP WHERE A.EMP_ID <>TMP.EMP_ID
```

But the select query is not returning any records. I have 1 million records i table. Can someone tell what wrong I am doing.

Comment: Not a clue what you are asking.   Please elaborate, or improve your example.

Comment: TMP table is blank..Thats why no records. You joining on EMP_ID with TMP table.

Comment: What does "in phase manner" mean? I am not familiar with the term / concept. What "conversion" are you doing - from what to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a join syntax that was used decades ago. The comma between your table translates to `CROSS JOIN`. So you have

```
SELECT A.EMP_ID 
FROM A
CROSS JOIN TMP 
WHERE A.EMP_ID <> TMP.EMP_ID;
```

A cross join combines every record in the left table with every record in the right table, so as to get all combinations. Your table TMP is empty, so your result set is also empty. (No matter what WHERE clause.)

Using proper ANSI joins, you can rewrite your query to

```
SELECT A.EMP_ID 
FROM A
INNER JOIN TMP ON A.EMP_ID <> TMP.EMP_ID;
```

which does exactly the same (only it applies the join criteria directly), and your result is still empty of course.

What you are probably looking for is this:

```
select emp_id from a
where emp_id not in (select emp_id from tmp);
```

which gets you all emp_id from A that are not (yet) in TMP.

Comment: Will below work?


select emp_id from a
where not exists (select 1 from tmp where tmp.emp_id=a.emp_id);

Comment: Yes, your `NOT EXISTS` clause does the same as my `NOT IN` clause. It's a matter of personal preference which to use. (`NOT IN` has the advantage of being simpler and the disadvantage that you must make sure not to select nulls inside the subquery. I assume that tmp.emp_id can never be null, hence no issue here.)

Comment: Thanks :) One more question.

If I add a.rownum <=50000 for table a, will it increase performance or it will still scan the whole table a.

Comment: I cannot say for sure, because that depends on the data and how the optimizer sees it. But it is very likely that this will speed up the query, because the process of searching for result rows can be stopped once 50000 rows have been found.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not returning any records because `tmp` is empty.  When you do a `cross join`, the number of records you get is the product of the records in the two tables.  If one has zero records, then you get zero records out.

So, I would simply suggest:

```
insert into tmp (emp_id)
    select A.EMP_ID 
    from A;
```

If you want to do this when `tmp` is not empty, then you would want additional logic to prevent duplicates.